# Shop in Subdomain feeding main domain order in admin area

Tags: admin, subdomains

I am working on a client's website which runs on wordpress and woocommerce, and they want to restructure their website. But it's how they envision it all working with their admin staff that is a cause for concern.

The brief is: the website currently runs with 2 separate demographics in mind. They have duplicate products and different services available (e.g. subscriptions, discount, etc). It is to be separated out by having the section that caters for one set of customers to be rebuilt as a subdomain.

Question: Can orders be fed into the main domain's admin area orders.

Question: Can customers be redirected to the subdomain depending on their role by a page by page basis? (And vice cersa).

Comment: Unfortunately since this is a plugin-based question you may not receive a lot of answers here - you might try a FB group instead. At first glance, I would be concerned about their desire to combine orders - that's not how WooCommerce works, and you may run into duplicate order number issues or all sorts of complications.

Comment: Yes, you could create a custom theme that checks role on every page and redirects them to the appropriate site (but unless they have an account on both sites they'll then not be logged in, so UX may not be great.) Better to have a gateway page where all non-logged-in users land, which explains they can choose from Site A if they're X type of person or Site B if they're Y type of person, and send them to the appropriate site from there.